# Formal invalidation of question about self-referential partial halting problem solver

Tags: computability, halting-problem

How do you formally invalidate a question about the decidability of a partial halting problem solver that answers correctly with the following kind of input: Turing machines that don't use the partial halting problem solver inside?

I made this question and it was marked as unclear. I deleted it. This is my question:

"Let H(M, i) be the halting set of M Turing machines with i input that don't have an H solver inside. Is there a way to prove this invalid or undecidable?

H is inside of a machine if by extracting some code from it you can solve H with that extracted code."

Comment: Re-posting your question a second time isn't helpful.  It still remains just as unclear the second time around.  In particular, the notion of "have a H solver inside" isn't well-defined.  What criteria would you use to determine whether it has a H solver inside?  What if the H solver has been obfuscated so you can no longer recognize it?  Also, I don't know what you mean by "formally invalidate a question", so I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you're asking why your question was closed as unclear, you should ask on [meta], not the main site -- but hopefully my comment explains why.

Comment: @D.W. I think solvers can exist inside Turing machines without being recognized. I'll be posting in Meta if I have the time.